# Superfish vertical dropdown menu z-index problem in ie7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, drop-down-menu, z-index, superfish

I found many questions about this issue and i tried all of the solution i found (z-index to parent, relative position to parent, the corner plugin etc...), but nothing seems to help. Here is the demo:

http://visztpeter.me/Develop/index.html

Works in all browser, except IE7. Any idea?

Comment: I my self did have this problem. I solved my problem using [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10439192/2044399). I didnt have the DOCTYPE element :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found a solution:

```
aside nav li{
z-index:1;
}

aside nav li.sfHover {
z-index:2;
}
```

So basicly i just need to add more z-index to the list element that has dropdown menu inside.